# Assigning analysis flag (ANL01FL) to last occurrence of a visit per parameter per subject

Tags: sas

I have a mapping specification for an analysis flag

"Flag any data required for safety summaries. Set ANL01FL to "Y" for: All scheduled visits from Week 1 to Week 16. **If multiple records satisfy these conditions within a single analysis visit, select only the latest occurring visit to set ANL01FL to "Y"**. Scheduled visits are the visits which will be included in the summaries for this particular type of data."

This is a mock up sample of data for 2 subjects

[image]

This is what I have attempted

```
proc sort data=advs out=stage1; by usubjid paramcd avalc visitnum; run;

data want(rename=(_anl01fl = anl01fl));
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.visitnum);
    set stage1;
    by usubjid paramcd avalc visitnum;
    length _anl01fl $2;
    _anl01fl = 'y';
    end;
    
    drop anl01fl;
run;
```

Anyone have any efficient recommendations/alternatives that doesn't involve too many proc sort/data steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
data have;
input USUBJID $ VISIT :$20. VISITNUM PARAMCD :$10. PARAM :$50.;
infile datalines dlm = '|';
datalines;
1001|Screening|1|BMI   |Body Mass Index (kg/m2)         
1001|Screening|1|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Day 1    |2|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Week 2   |4|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Week 4   |5|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Week 8   |6|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Week 12  |7|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001|Screening|1|HEIGHT|Height (cm)                     
1001|Screening|1|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1001|Day 1    |2|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1001|Week 2   |4|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1001|Week 4   |5|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1001|Week 8   |6|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1001|Week 12  |7|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1002|Screening|1|BMI   |Body Mass Index (kg/m2)         
1002|Screening|1|DIABP |Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1002|Screening|1|HEIGHT|Height (cm)                     
1002|Screening|1|HR    |Heart Rate (beats/min)          
1002|Screening|1|RESP  |Respiratory Rate (breaths/min)  
1002|Screening|1|SYSBP |Systolic Blood Pressure (mmHg)  
1002|Screening|1|TEMP  |Temperature (C)                 
1002|Screening|1|WEIGHT|Weight (kg)                     
;

proc sort data = have;
   by USUBJID VISITNUM;
run;

data want(drop = r week);
   set have;
   by USUBJID VISITNUM;
   if first.VISITNUM then r = 0;

   week = ifn(find(visit, 'Week'), compress(visit, , 'kd'), .);
   if week in (1 : 16, 20) then r = 1;

   if last.VISITNUM and r = 1 then ANL01FL = 'Y';

   retain r;
run;
```

**Result**

```
USUBJID  VISIT      VISITNUM  PARAMCD  PARAM                            ANL01FL 
1001     Screening  1         BMI      Body Mass Index (kg/m2) 
1001     Screening  1         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Screening  1         HEIGHT   Height (cm) 
1001     Screening  1         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min) 
1001     Day 1      2         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Day 1      2         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min) 
1001     Week 2     4         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Week 2     4         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min)           Y
1001     Week 4     5         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Week 4     5         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min)           Y
1001     Week 8     6         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Week 8     6         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min)           Y
1001     Week 12    7         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1001     Week 12    7         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min)           Y
1002     Screening  1         BMI      Body Mass Index (kg/m2) 
1002     Screening  1         DIABP    Diastolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1002     Screening  1         HEIGHT   Height (cm) 
1002     Screening  1         HR       Heart Rate (beats/min) 
1002     Screening  1         RESP     Respiratory Rate (breaths/min) 
1002     Screening  1         SYSBP    Systolic Blood Pressure (mmHg) 
1002     Screening  1         TEMP     Temperature (C) 
1002     Screening  1         WEIGHT   Weight (kg)
```

Comment: Hi,



I was reviewing my program and noticed this

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
106:36

@PeterClemmensen Seems to be specifically to the compress section of                                                                                                     
      week = ifn(find(visit, 'Week'), compress(visit, , 'kd'), .);​
Tried modifying it but can't seem to get rid of it.